# Topic Modeling in R language

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-r

I have one question about something ,I'm applying Topic Modeling - LDA in R language and I used it to determine the topics of the user's tweets , I notice something when I'm using this command to get the tweets ( the last 500 tweets without retweets) sometime I got 500 and sometime I got 130 and sometimes I got 45 for different users but with the same n=500  , what is the factor behind that

```
tweets <- userTimeline("BarackObama",n=500,includeRts = FALSE)
```

[image]

also if I want to remove the name of user from tweets how I can do that in R because I noticed the accuracy of clustering Topics it's not good , I don't know how we can measure the percentage of accuracy for this thing in R .
Last question about if the TwitterR support arabic tweets or not !

Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: Thank you for your note , I updated something in the post may be it was become more understandable

Comment: Ask one question at a time. Clearly show which packages you are using. Not all data is available via the Twitter API. There are restrictions on how far back in time you can do. You can read their [developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation). (What ever package you are using to import data can't do anything the Twitter API doesn't support.)

Comment: I'm using TwitterR package for fetching data from Twitter

Comment: @SamahAhmed, it's called `twitteR`